# Xsd choice in wsdl producing error

Tags: java, xsd, wsdl, cxf

I'm currently working on a wsdl/soap project using Java/apache cxf. In the wsdl file, the xsd part includes a xsd external file.
When I build my file (using wsdl2java) everything runs fine. However when I try to open the web page and to use the javascript generated by cxf, I have the following error:

```
May 24, 2011 11:34:32 AM org.apache.cxf.common.xmlschema.XmlSchemaUtils unsupportedConstruct
SEVERE: GROUP_CHILD
May 24, 2011 11:34:32 AM org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination doService
WARNING: writeResponse failed: 
org.apache.cxf.common.xmlschema.UnsupportedConstruct: GROUP_CHILD
...
```

I tried to catch the error and I found something in the following block:

```
<xsd:complexType name="Scenario">
    <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="description" type="tns:Description" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:choice>
            <xsd:element name="coordinates_center_position" type="tns:GeoCoord3D"/>
            <xsd:element name="coordinates_center_position_link" type="tns:FileLink"/>
        </xsd:choice>
        <xsd:choice minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:element name="environment_parameters" type="tns:EnvironmentParameters"/>
            <xsd:element name="environment_parameters_link" type="tns:FileLink"/>
        </xsd:choice>
        <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:element name="entity_object" type="tns:EntityObject"/>
            <xsd:element name="entity_object_link" type="tns:FileLink"/>
        </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

The last choice is producing the error, but the error disappear (and everything works fine) if I'm commenting one of the 2 element (the commented element can be either one).

I am missing something on the cxf or xsd behavior? Or is this a bug?

P.S: I'm relatively new to all this stuff so if you need something else to elude this or if I'm not clear enough, just tell me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to replace the repeating xsd:choice using the pattern below. Technically, they are equivalent - yet, it may get you around a limitation - as it may be related to the use of the xsd:choice.

This:

```
<xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xsd:element name="a"/>
    <xsd:element name="b"/>
</xsd:choice>
```

can be replaced by:

```
<xsd:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xsd:element name="a" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xsd:element name="b" minOccurs="0"/>
</xsd:sequence>
```

Comment: While this may work, this does not seem equivalent to me.
In the second case, you can have the a and b children and it's still valid.

The choice is included in the sequence, but the opposite is false :)

Comment: I believe your confusion comes from ignoring the effect of the "unbounded" on the choice; it does allow for an <a/> to be followed by a <b/> - still valid. Read it this way: first choice <a/>, second choice <b/>, etc.

Comment: Ah yes my bad, I forgot the unbounded on the choice, my comment was not taking that into account.
I'll try you solution during the day to see if it'll work :)

Comment: So after a test, it is really equivalent. It's producing the same error, and it's also disappearing if one of the child is commented.

Comment: It looks like a limitation in the current implementation. After a bit more digging, I found the code posted [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/cxf/common/xmlschema/XmlSchemaUtils.java.html); it seems that groups are not supported yet.